# Copy Keyframes From One Channel to Another?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

[image]

Is it possible to copy the keyframes from the *X Location* channel in the *Graph Editor* and paste them into the *Default Value (Strength)* channel? The second channel pertains to a keyframed *Emission* shader's *Strength:* value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

[image]

Key <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice until everything is selected. Then <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> select the *X Location* channel. You should see only it highlighted in white.

[image]

Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the red keyframes. <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> select the *Default Value (Strength)* channel. Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste.

[image]